# Issue binding a ExtJS Grid to a form

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I'm trying to bind a form from a datagrid (ExtJS) here's the code running:

**[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2n6)**

The grid loads perfectly but when I click a row the firebug console displays

`TypeError: form is null`

and the form doesn't get loaded with the data in the row I'm selecting. I really need some help right here, I feel stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code like below :

```
                xtype: 'form',
                // give an id to the form
                id: 'config-form',
                height: 473,
                width: 510,
                layout: 'absolute',
                bodyPadding: 10,
                title: 'Configuracion',

                ...

                listeners: {
                    itemclick:function(gridview, record){
                         var form = Ext.getCmp('config-form');
                         form.loadRecord(record);
                    }
        }
```

You had a mistaken which you used `up` method but `up` method didn't find the container!